# Transporting and deserialization of Point structure between WPF and XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, serialization

Assume I have WPF application and Windows 8 Store Application and I want to exchange some data between. So I need to serialize and deserialize them, but I currently have problem with deserializating Point structure in my DTO objects:

(Windows 8 store app definition)

```cs
using Windows.Foundation;

namespace DTO
{
    public class ImageMessageDTO : BaseDTO
    {
        public virtual Point ProblematicPoint { get; set; }
    }
}
```

(WPF definition)

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace DTO
{
    public class ImageMessageDTO : BaseDTO
    {
        public virtual Point ProblematicPoint { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see, DTO objects are identical, except for the namespace where Point is defined on different platforms.

While deserializing to WPF DTO, I'm getting following error:

> Additional information: Error in line 1 position 256. 'EndElement'
>   'ProblematicPoint ' from namespace
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DTO'
>   is not expected. Expecting element '_x'.

How should I serialize and deserialize objects?

Comment: Is it Xml serialization or data contract serialization? Can you add the xml of the serialized object?

Answer (score 0):

Your classes are obviously **NOT** equal since they're defined in different assemblies. The serializer is never going to identify these separate classes as one single unit.

This is what [Portable Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) were created for.

Put your DTO in a PCL, and then reference that library from both your WPF project and your WinRT project:

```
- Solution MyApplication
   |--> MyApplication.Model (Portable Class library)
   |      |--> - ImageMessageDTO
   |
   |--> MyApplication.WPF (WPF Application)
   |      |--> References
   |            |--> MyApplication.Model
   |
   |--> MyApplication.WinRT (WinRT Application)
          |--> References
                |--> MyApplication.Model
```

Comment: I considered this option as well but Point is not supported in PCL (together with other properties I have in different DTO classes, for example BitmapSource). How would you solve that?